# Bash: How to enforce output to one line?

Tags: bash

I wrote the following Nagios check, which checks `/etc/fstab` for mounts and by using `df` checks if they are mounted properly:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Check mounts based on /etc/fstab
grep="/bin/grep"
awk="/bin/awk"
df="/bin/df"
mounts=$($grep nfs /etc/fstab | $awk '{print $2}')

# Check if mounts exist
for mount in $mounts; do
$df | $grep $mount &>/dev/null
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
msg="Mount $mount is mounted!"
else
msg="Mount $mount is not mounted!"
fi
echo $msg
done
```

When I run the check it returns a proper result:

```
[root@nyproxy5 ~]# ./check_mount.sh 
Mount /proxy_logs is mounted!
Mount /proxy_dump is mounted!
Mount /sync_logs is mounted!
[root@nyproxy5 ~]#
```

But I want the output of the script to be 1 line rather than 3 lines, how can it be achieved?
I realize that the way the script is written at the moment doesn't allow it, even the "Mount X is mounted" message should be changed, but I'm having a hard time with the logic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The variables containing command names are just wacky. Make sure you have `/bin` in your `PATH` and use the actual, pathless command names.

Comment: `mounts=$(awk '/nfs/{print $2}' /etc/fstab)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `echo $msg` to `echo -n $msg`

`-n` option will avoid printing newline

Answer (score 0):

There is a general solution in case of some complicated command. Newlines or any other character could be removed this way:

```
./script.sh | tr -d '\n'
```

Or a win32 executable in cygwin:

```
./asd.exe | tr -d '\r\n'
```