# Bash: How can I read from file and display the output in one line?

Tags: bash, parsing

I'd like to run:

```
grep nfs /etc/fstab | awk '{print $2}'

[root@nyproxy5 ~]# grep nfs /etc/fstab | awk '{print $2}'
/proxy_logs
/proxy_dump
/sync_logs
[root@nyproxy5 ~]#
```

And to get the output in one line delimited by space.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash: How to enforce output to one line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296773/bash-how-to-enforce-output-to-one-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind a space (and no newline) at the end, you could do use this awk script:

```
awk '/nfs/{printf "%s ", $2}' /etc/fstab
```

For lines that match the pattern /nfs/, the second column is printed followed by a space. As a general rule, piping grep into awk is unnecessary as awk can do the pattern matching itself.

If you would like a newline at the end, you could use the `END` block:

```
awk '/nfs/{printf "%s ", $2}END{print ""}' /etc/fstab
```

This prints an empty string, followed by the output record separator (which is a newline). This will mean that you always have a newline in the output even if no matching records were found. If that's a problem, you could use a flag:

```
awk '/nfs/{f=1;printf "%s ", $2}END{if(f)print ""}' /etc/fstab
```

The flag `f` is set to true if the pattern is ever matched, causing the newline to be printed.

Answer (score 1):

Newlines or any other character could be removed or replaced with `tr` command:

```
grep nfs /etc/fstab | awk '{print $2}' | tr -c '\n' ' '
```

If you want to get rid of tabs also:

```
 | tr -c '\t' ' '
```